# Best way to find translation of onscreen text in anime?

Tags: anime-production

i.e Tomodachi Game EP01 13:20 - Relevant text displayed on chalkboard not translated.
I see this all the time and it bothers me so much.

Is there a simple way to find this translated information?
Would fansubs have this? If so is there a community I can find them in?

Is there an archive of translated information for anime that I can reference?

I'd like to avoid having to manually translate through screen capture and translation software if at all possible.

I am hoping there has been someone with this problem before and an acceptable solution was implemented and i have just failed to locate such a solution.

Comment: Fansubs may add TL (translator's) note, though this community can't provide resource due to it being gray area.

Comment: If you just want to get a quick grasp in the moment, google lens tends to work to give you the general gist.

Comment: Fansubs usually translated these kind of things, but then fansubs aren't really a thing that exist anymore in the sense that they all just rip from streaming sources instead of translating themselves. Truly a shame, their translations were more accurate.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Are you referring to the famous meme ["According to keikaku"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/just-according-to-keikaku)?

Comment: To OP: I don't have all the information for a complete answer but you can have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_snS5DfSdg) made by a popular Anituber.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami not really, just based on my recollection back then that fansubs may add a translator's note for non-conversational text. Apparently, official subs also do that to some extent, like [Netflix Komi Anime Doesn’t Translate Some Of The Text In The Series](https://www.gamerbraves.com/netflix-komi-anime-doesnt-translate-some-of-the-text-in-the-series/) and its linked Twitter conversation mentioning [how Crunchyroll did it](https://twitter.com/PurposeDevoid/status/1451282972976496643).

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't a solution, unless the subtitles provide it for you.

This is actually fairly common in that, on certain occasions, the subtitles *will* include the text that is on a screen or on a sign somewhere.

If they do not, then there's not much other recourse to solve the issue besides using Google Translate on your own (which is always going to be hit or miss).